# In fragment I want to click back how to show alert dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I am using navigation menu in an Activity. When I click menu, it goes to particular fragment that time I give `addtobackstack(null)`. I want to fix these 2 issues:

1. I want to show `do you want to exit app` through a popup In the back fragment
2. Assume that I traverse from Fragment A to B and then B to C. If I give back in the Fragment C I want to come the main page, without showing the Fragment B.

This is my Home Activity:

```
package school.wyse.app.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;


public class ParentHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ServerUtils servutil;
    GridLayoutManager grid;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private View navHeader;
    LinearLayout profile;
    ImageView msglist;
    ArrayList<StudentProfile> lang_list_new;
    public RecyclerView studentsListRecyclerView;
     public ParentMenuDashoard mStudAdapter;
    StudentProfile[] profiles;
    private StudentProfile[] studentCachedData;
    Context ctx;
   DrawerLayout drawer;
    ImageView imageViewstaff;

    String tenent_id,profilename,image,userphone;

    Integer id,roleid;
    String backStateName;
    TextView profile_phone,profile_name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent_home);
           backStateName = this.getClass().getName();
            ctx=this;
         Toast.makeText(ctx, "backStateName--"+backStateName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            navHeader=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            studentsListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.messageWindowRecycler);


            ParentDashboard parentDashboard = new ParentDashboard();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, parentDashboard, parentDashboard.getTag()).commit();
            toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {

          DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {


                super.onBackPressed();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
  /*  if (id == R.id.action_msg) {
            return true;
        }*/

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
            ParentDashboard parentDashboard = new ParentDashboard();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, parentDashboard, parentDashboard.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            //toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_teachers) {
            TeacherList teacherList = new TeacherList();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

          //  manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_content_frame, accountsMenuListFragment, "AccountsMenu").addToBackStack(" ").commit();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, teacherList, teacherList.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
          //  toolbar.setTitle("Teachers");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_attendance) {
            AttendanceFragment attendanceFragment = new AttendanceFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, attendanceFragment, attendanceFragment.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
           // toolbar.setTitle("Attendance");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_consumablity) {
            ParentConsumablityFragment parentConsumablityFragment = new ParentConsumablityFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, parentConsumablityFragment, parentConsumablityFragment.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            // toolbar.setTitle("Attendance");

        }
        else {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: First of all, please use `switch` instead of `if else` *cry*

Comment: Second of all, you can keep an `ArrayList<Fragment>` with 2 public methods in your activity `add` and `remove` which will get called when you add or remove a fragment. Inside `onBackPressed` just check if array is empty (in this case close the app) otherwise, remove child(item from array)

Comment: can you please send me sample code please

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry for late reply

This part goes in `onBackPressed()` of your activity, which basically check if you have fragments attached (so it won't perform the native back, which closes the app)

```
if (childFragments.size() > 0) {
        if (childFragments.get((childFragments.size() - 1)) != null) {
            childFragments.remove(childFragments.size() - 1);
            return;
        }
    }
```

All you have to do is `add/remove` items to this array every time you `attach / detach` fragments :)

For your particular case when you are on fragment C and want to go back to fragment A without showing fragment B, I suggest you make a public function that remove all fragments from `ArrayList` except last one (from position 0)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use below code in mainactivity where you want to show appexit:

   ```
        @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

   if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
       super.onBackPressed();
       finish();
       return;
   }
   this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
       }
   }, 2000);
   ```

   }
2. When moving fragment A to B do not add "addbackstack". When moving fragment B to C add "addbackstack("C")"

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have to take care of your second issue as it will lead to easy handle for the first issue, hence you have to take care of how to initiate the fragments in order to always coming to the first fragment while hitting back regardless the flow of fragments that lead to the current fragment, to do so, just initiate the fragments like the following:

```
/**
 * To initiate any fragment
 */
private void showAnyFragment(Fragment fragmentToShow) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, fragmentToShow)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}

/**
 * When (for a reason) you want to initiate the main fragment (FragmentA)
 */
private void homeClicked() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Now, `fragmentA` is your main fragment, when going from `A` to `B` to `C` to `D` and click back button it will go back to `A` directly.

Coming to your second issue, it will be straight forward as you already keeping only `fragmentA` always in the back stack, so `onBackPressed()` function of the Activity will not be called unless there are No other fragment other than `FragmentA`is being displayed(e.g if you are in `fragmentC` and you click back button, the `onBackPressed()` function will not be called), so you are sure that when you come inside `onBackPressed()` function of the activity that the currently running fragment is `FragmentA` which is your main page fragment.

so if you want to display a popup while the user trying to exit the app (he would be in `FragmentA` and hiitting Back), all you have to do is to override the `onBackPressed()` method of the `MainActivity` that holds the fragments:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // the user here is in FragmentA(main page),
          and he is clicking back to exit the app.
  // TODO show popup here or do whatever you want
}
```